# Problems finding the solution to the differential equation. $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{3}{4}y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{3}{4}y=0$$

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+r}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r) c_nx^{n+r-1}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)(n+r-1) c_nx^{n+r-2}$$

Plugging into the differential equation we obtain

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)(n+r-1) c_nx^{n+r}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)c_nx^{n+r}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+r}=0$$

Taking out first few terms we obtain the incidal equation

$$r(r-1)-(r)+\frac{3}{4}=0$$

$$(r-\frac{3}{2})(r-\frac{1}{2})=0$$

Does it mean that the new solution is just

$$y=c_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+\frac{3}{2}}+c_2\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$

Is it the right way? What is the reasoning behind this? It seems like $c_1$, $c_2$ and the rest are zeroes. Except $c_0$

Comment: On the second line, assume the form $y=x^{r}$ ... On the final line, conclude the general solution $y=Ax^{1/2}+Bx^{3/2}$ ... you did not need any of the series stuff !

Comment: It is just that straightforward? The question seems like a trap.

Comment: Don't use the same $c$ (as in $c_1$ and $c_2$) for the overall constants as well as the coefficients.

Comment: That happens to be an "equi-potential" equation (or "Euler" type equation) because the power of x in each term is the same as the order of the derivative.  That is why the substitution Donald Splutterwit gives works.  The substitution x= ln(t) converts this to an equation with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Cauchy-Euler equation. Using $y = x^m$ is a bit simpler.